# Combination and Permutation Question Related to Ice Cream Scoops.

Tags: combinatorics

If an ice cream store offers $31$ different flavors. How many three scoop cones are possible if:

1) The flavors need not be different and the order is unimportant?

2) Flavors need not be different and the order of the flavors is important?

I am looking mostly for a second opinion. I got $9331$ for part $1$, and I got $85591$ for part $2$.

Comment: Can you show your work? It will be more useful that way.

Comment: I get $5456$ for the first one.  Please show us how you got your answers.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, it's just the "bars and stars problem", so you should get $\binom{33}{3}=5456$. The second is just $31^3=29791$.  I'm not sure how you got your answers but they don't look correct to me.

Comment: I think the first posting had "unimportant," but in the version now, you are correct.  (+1)